# Can you extract track activity history from SoundCloud API?

Tags: soundcloud

Is it possible to extract track activity history? Time series metrics such as Playback, Download, Favoritings, Comments by day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soundcloud Api itself doesn't have such option.

What you could do is either subtract the values of 2 variables (one for today and one for the previous day) or do it from a third party website (like a follow-to-download gate) that track the downloads etc